# Windows 7 restricted network bandwidth

Tags: networking, windows-7

I have a Windows 7 laptop on a personal WiFi network. When I try to do anything with significant network traffic, like stream video, it has periods where it shows traffic of around 3Mbps (which is what I expect for this setup), but then long periods - up to hours - where it caps at tens of kilobytes, causing jittery streaming. During those periods the traffic rate never goes above a couple of tens of Kb, no matter what I am doing.

- I have another Windows 7 box on the same network, which always streams at the expected rate, so it's not a problem with the network or the ISP.
- I've tried resetting the network adapter, and that fixes the problem for a while, but it comes back quickly
- I've run a full McAfee malware scan
- The CPU load is low
- No other processes are using the network, and no other computers are using the network.
- Behaviour is the same whether I am using Chrome or Explorer
- Machine works fine through Ethernet.
- Adapter is a builtin Centrino Wireless N 1030
- WiFi driver is "up to date" (2010!)

I've noticed that any change to the Wireless adapter settings, or a network disconnect/connnect results in good traffic speed for a few minutes, but it then drops back to a few Kbps.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you able to test with that laptop and an Ethernet cable instead to rule out Wireless issues with the adapter... or alternatively connect to another wireless network and test although this would not rule out incompatibility between the Wireless device and the adapter...

Comment: Edited into question.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this as follows:

1. Downloaded new wireless/bluetooth drivers from here: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/search?keyword=Intel%C2%AE+Centrino%C2%AE+Wireless-N+1030 . After installation the driver didn't show up as more recent, but the installation had an effect.
2. Turned off 802.1n mode

Both changes were needed to fix the problem.